# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED in node.js - database

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'am new in node.js and learning it from book. I have some code in book and it's generate me an error when i started it. I'am looking here for solution but anyone have solution to me. So I decided to ask my own question.

My code is running with postgreSQL and it's `require('pg');`. It's already installed in `node_modules`

Here is my all code from one file:
postgreSQL.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "tcp://root:root@localhost:5432/dataBase";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

client.query(
    'insert into users (name, age) values ("$1, $2") returning id',
    ['Michal', 29],
    function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('Id form this record '+ result.rows[0].id);
    }
);
```

and when I want to start it it's generate me an error in cmd:

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

I'am trying to check the port in telnet, debug my code and every solutions from here. Anyone help ?

Comment: Are you can connect to postgreSQL with user root at localhost through command line?

Comment: only when i set: `node debug postgreSQL.js`
and then in cmd via telnet:
`telnet localhost 5858`

Comment: I means if this works: `psql -U root dataBase` - run by command line.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause could be connection with postgreSQL. Try `telnet localhost 5432`. If it listening, try to connect by command line:

**Windows:**

```
cd C:\path\to\postgres\bin
psql.exe -U root dataBase
```

**Linux:**

```
psql -U root dataBase
```

If connection failed, you need to verify the connection with database:

1. Port it's listening (5432)
2. Config at pg_hba.conf
3. User and database name (in this case is root and dataBase)

Comment: yea that's really help me! I'am working on default server in postgreSQL because i can't create my own but it's not problem now.

Comment: Perhaps the user is postgres.

Comment: Yea, i use that to ceonnect, next I create my own relation and it's working. Only one thing is strange to me, why in postgresql auto_increment is serial. In mysql i'm using auto_increment. But now everything working, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to their [Documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client), it looks like the protocol expected for the communication is postgres not tcp. Try changing your conString to

`'postgres://root:root@localhost:5432/dataBase'`

This changes the protocol from tcp to postgres which is what the database is expecting when you communicate with it.

Comment: I change that but it wouldn't help me. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the mysql connection port by this command

```
ps ax |grep mysqld
```

result should be like " mysql.sock --port=3300 "

Then go to the mysql folder under **node_modules** and open **ConnectionConfig.js** file > change **port** to correct one "3300"